# Set new value trigger

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to be able to calculate the age of my customers before inserting data into my table... hence a trigger is appropriate. So I have a CUSTOMER table that contains the value "age" which is an INT.

I'm not sure if my syntax is off but it keeps giving me an error. Below is my code, can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Thanks

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insert_new_musc_record  
BEFORE INSERT ON CUSTOMER FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
DECLARE x INT;
SET x= DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(NEW.dob))/365);
SET @NEW.age= x;
END $$ 
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Can you include the error message as well?

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax... .... ...  to use near '); SET @NEW.age=x; END' at line 5.  Thanks

Comment: @AlexG: This was due to an extra first bracket, please check my answer, and see whether it is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this::

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insert_new_musc_record  
BEFORE INSERT ON CUSTOMER FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
DECLARE x INT;
SET x := (DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(NEW.dob))/365);
SET @NEW.age= x;
END $$ 
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you. Do you mind explaining the difference between ':=' and just '='. Like when would you use each? Will accept

Comment: It is great, that I helped and it worked...
It is just a Syntax which MYSQL supports, with '=' it wont set the value to that variable

Comment: There is also another syntax of setting a variable, in your case it would be just ::

`Select DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(NEW.dob))/365 into x;`

in place of
SET x := (DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(NEW.dob))/365);